# On-premise Enterprise Social Network Application

Tags: self-hosted, social-networks

We want to build an internal social network within our corporate. We have tried Yammer and the features are good. However we cannot accept cloud service due to regulation.

Is there any on-premise (non-cloud, self-hosted) Enterprise Social Network Application you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [OpenSocial](https://www.drupal.org/project/social) which can be installed and run on-premise. It's open-source and actually a Drupal Distribution.

> Open Social is a great match for knowledge sharing, communities of practice and ideation communities. It's used by NGOs, governments and hundreds of organizations, big and small, to connect to their members, volunteers and customers.